# OnTouchEvent in different class than the main

Tags: java, android, touch-event

Is this possible, to make an OnTouchEvent method in class other than for example `public class MySurfaceView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback`? I mean, that's my main class, where everything happens. I tried with listeners, but can't get them working at all...

I just need to create a totally separate class for touch events. For sensors it worked by passing the Sensor object from MainActivity into the SurfaceView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can set `OnTouchListener` on any class that inherits `View` with the `setOnTouchListener()` method.

You can make it to be separate class that implements `View.OnTouchListener`.

```
public class MyTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener
{
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
    {
        // your code goes here
        return false;
    }
}
```

then

```
myView.setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener());
```